# React Native: Different styles applied on orientation change

Tags: css, reactjs, screen-orientation, react-native

I'm developing a **React Native** application to be deployed as a native application on iOS and Android (and Windows, if possible).

The problem is that we want the layout to be different **depending on screen dimensions and its orientation.**

I've made some functions that return the **styles object** and are called on every component render's function, so I am able to apply different styles at application startup, but if the orientation (or screen's size) changes once the app has been initialized, they aren't recalculated nor reapplied.

I've added listeners to the top rendered so it updates its state on orientation change (and it forces a render for the rest of the application), but the subcomponents are not rerendering (because, in fact, **they have not been changed**).

So, **my question is:** how can I make to have styles that may be **completely different** based on screen size and orientation, just as with **CSS Media Queries** (which are rendered on the fly)?

*I've already tried [react-native-responsive](https://github.com/adbayb/react-native-responsive) module without luck.*

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559463/9444013 try this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I've been able to do so. Don't know the performance issues it can carry, but they should not be a problem since it's only called on resizing or orientation change.

I've made a global controller where I have a function which receives the component (the container, the view) and adds an event listener to it:

```
const getScreenInfo = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get('window');
    return dim;
}    

const bindScreenDimensionsUpdate = (component) => {
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
        try{
            component.setState({
                orientation: isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape',
                screenWidth: getScreenInfo().width,
                screenHeight: getScreenInfo().height
            });
        }catch(e){
            // Fail silently
        }
    });
}
```

With this, I force to rerender the component when there's a change on orientation, or on window resizing.

Then, on every component constructor:

```
import ScreenMetrics from './globalFunctionContainer';

export default class UserList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    ScreenMetrics.bindScreenDimensionsUpdate(this);
  }
}
```

This way, it gets rerendered everytime there's a window resize or an orientation change.

**You should note**, however, that this must be applied to every component which we want to listen to orientation changes, since if the parent container is updated but the `state` (or `props`) of the children do not update, they won't be rerendered, so **it can be a performance kill** if we have a big children tree listening to it.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: You might have a memory leak, the event listener is not removed? Might affect performance too since there could potentially become many callbacks to call when they are not removed over time.

Comment: Yes, as I already explain in my answer, it can be a performance kill depending on the number of items attached to the listener. If you remove the listener, though, it won't update the UI next time you change the orientation, so it's not useful neither to remove them.

Comment: It is useful to remove the listener when the component is unmounted. If you do not you will eventually run out of memory.

Answer (score 64):

If using Hooks. You can refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838183/5648340

The orientation of apps from portrait to landscape and vice versa is a task that sounds easy but may be tricky in react native when the view has to be changed when orientation changes. In other words, having different views defined for the two orientations can be achieved by considering these two steps.

**Import Dimensions from React Native**

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

**To identify the current orientation and render the view accordingly**

```
/**
 * Returns true if the screen is in portrait mode
 */
const isPortrait = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
    return dim.height >= dim.width;
};
 
/**
 * Returns true of the screen is in landscape mode
 */
const isLandscape = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
    return dim.width >= dim.height;
};
```

**To know when orientation changes to change view accordingly**

```
// Event Listener for orientation changes
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
        this.setState({
            orientation: Platform.isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
        });
    });
```

**Assembling all pieces**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    /**
    * Returns true if the screen is in portrait mode
    */
    const isPortrait = () => {
      const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
      return dim.height >= dim.width;
    };

    this.state = {
      orientation: isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
    };

    // Event Listener for orientation changes
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
      this.setState({
        orientation: isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
      });
    });

  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.orientation === 'portrait') {
      return (
          //Render View to be displayed in portrait mode
       );
    }
    else {
      return (
        //Render View to be displayed in landscape mode
      );
    }

  }
}
```

As the event defined for looking out the orientation change uses this command ‘**this.setState()**’, this method automatically again calls for ‘**render()**’ so we don’t have to worry about rendering it again, it’s all taken care of.

Comment: Please post code as text in the answer, not as images. You can format the code as a code block using Ctrl + K or the `{}` button on top of the editor.

Comment: Thanks @FeiXiang. I have made the changes.

Comment: If a device is made that is wider than it is tall, this solution will not work on it.

Comment: Does this also work for web? And does it work with expo?  They seems to use a different API to get the dimensions: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationgetorientationasync

Comment: You're not removing the listener on unmount.

Answer (score 42):

Here's @Mridul Tripathi's answer as a reusable hook:

```
// useOrientation.tsx
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

/**
 * Returns true if the screen is in portrait mode
 */
const isPortrait = () => {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
  return dim.height >= dim.width;
};

/**
 * A React Hook which updates when the orientation changes
 * @returns whether the user is in 'PORTRAIT' or 'LANDSCAPE'
 */
export function useOrientation(): 'PORTRAIT' | 'LANDSCAPE' {
  // State to hold the connection status
  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState<'PORTRAIT' | 'LANDSCAPE'>(
    isPortrait() ? 'PORTRAIT' : 'LANDSCAPE',
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const callback = () => setOrientation(isPortrait() ? 'PORTRAIT' : 'LANDSCAPE');

    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', callback);

    return () => {
      Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', callback);
    };
  }, []);

  return orientation;
}
```

You can then consume it using:

```
import {useOrientation} from './useOrientation';

export const MyScreen = () => {
    const orientation = useOrientation();

    return (
        <View style={{color: orientation === 'PORTRAIT' ? 'red' : 'blue'}} />
    );
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add the `[]` as the second parameter for your `useEffect`, otherwise the effect hook will be running indefinitely.

Comment: What if I want to use orientation without component ? Is there any solution for this

Comment: NB: const dim = Dimensions.get('screen'); 

should be 
const dim = Dimensions.get('window');

Comment: @AzeezatRaheem not necessarily. `window` is the size of the visible Application window. `screen` is the size of the device's screen. [src](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions#addeventlistener)

Comment: This almost worked, but I had to modify it as show in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dpyHY--bVQ

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `onLayout` prop:

```
export default class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      screen: Dimensions.get('window'),
    };
  }

  getOrientation(){
    if (this.state.screen.width > this.state.screen.height) {
      return 'LANDSCAPE';
    }else {
      return 'PORTRAIT';
    }
  }

  getStyle(){
    if (this.getOrientation() === 'LANDSCAPE') {
      return landscapeStyles;
    } else {
      return portraitStyles;
    }
  }
  onLayout(){
    this.setState({screen: Dimensions.get('window')});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={this.getStyle().container} onLayout = {this.onLayout.bind(this)}>

      </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const portraitStyles = StyleSheet.create({
 ...
});

const landscapeStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a super light component that addresses this issue.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-orientation-view

The component re-renders it's content upon orientation change.
You can, for example, pass landscapeStyles and portraitStyles to display these orientations differently.
Works on iOS and Android.
It's easy to use. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After the orientation change the layout didn't change.
Then I understood one simple idea - layout should depend on screen width that should be calculated inside render function, i.e.

```
getScreen = () => {
  return Dimensions.get('screen');
}

render () {
  return (
    <View style={{ width: this.getScreen().width }>
      // your code
    </View>
  );
}
```

In that case, the width will be calculated at the moment of render.

Answer (score 2):

React Native also have `useWindowDimensions` hooks that returns the width and height of your device.

With this, you can check easily if the device is in 'Portrait' or 'Landscape' by comparing the width and height.

See more [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions#docsNav)

Answer (score 1):

** I am using this logic for my landscape and portrait Logic.**
** by this if I launch my app in landscape first I am getting the real height of my device. and manage the hight of the header accordingly.**

> ```
> const [deviceOrientation, setDeviceOrientation] = useState(
>     Dimensions.get('window').width < Dimensions.get('window').height
>       ? 'portrait'
>       : 'landscape'
>   );
>   const [deviceHeight, setDeviceHeight] = useState(
>     Dimensions.get('window').width < Dimensions.get('window').height
>       ? Dimensions.get('window').height
>       : Dimensions.get('window').width
>   );
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const setDeviceHeightAsOrientation = () => {
>       if (Dimensions.get('window').width < Dimensions.get('window').height) {
>         setDeviceHeight(Dimensions.get('window').height);
>       } else {
>         setDeviceHeight(Dimensions.get('window').width);
>       }
>     };
>     Dimensions.addEventListener('change', setDeviceHeightAsOrientation);
>     return () => {
>       //cleanup work
>       Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', setDeviceHeightAsOrientation);
>     };
>   });
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const deviceOrientation = () => {
>       if (Dimensions.get('window').width < Dimensions.get('window').height) {
>         setDeviceOrientation('portrait');
>       } else {
>         setDeviceOrientation('landscape');
>       }
>     };
>     Dimensions.addEventListener('change', deviceOrientation);
>     return () => {
>       //cleanup work
>       Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', deviceOrientation);
>     };
>   });
>   console.log(deviceHeight);
>   if (deviceOrientation === 'landscape') {
>     return (
>       <View style={[styles.header, { height: 60, paddingTop: 10 }]}>
>         <TitleText>{props.title}</TitleText>
>       </View>
>     );
>   } else {
>     return (
>       <View
>         style={[
>           styles.header,
>           {
>             height: deviceHeight >= 812 ? 90 : 60,
>             paddingTop: deviceHeight >= 812 ? 36 : 10
>           }
>         ]}>
>         <TitleText>{props.title}</TitleText>
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```js
const CheckOrient = () => {
  console.log('screenHeight:' + Dimensions.get('screen').height + ', screenWidth: ' + Dimensions.get('screen').width);
}

return ( <
    View onLayout = {
      () => CheckOrient()
    } >
    ............
    <
    /View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have, by far, had the most success with this library: https://github.com/axilis/react-native-responsive-layout
It does what you are asking for and a lot more.  Simple Component implementation without hardly any logic like some of the more complex answers above.  My project is using Phone, Tablet, **and web via RNW** - and the implementation is flawless.  Additionally when resizing the browser it's truly responsive, and not just on initial rendering - handling phone orientation changes flawlessly.

Example code (Put any components as children of blocks):

```
<Grid>
  <Section> {/* Light blue */}
    <Block xsSize="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
    <Block xsSize="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
    <Block xsSize="1/1" smSize="1/2" /> 
  </Section>
  <Section> {/* Dark blue */}
    <Block size="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
    <Block size="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
    <Block size="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
    <Block size="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
    <Block size="1/1" smSize="1/2" />
  </Section>
</Grid>
```

To give this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have written a HoC solution for my **expo** SDK36 project, it support orientation change and pass `props.orientation` based on `ScreenOrientation.Orientation` value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScreenOrientation } from 'expo';

export default function withOrientation(Component) {
  class DetectOrientation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        orientation: '',
      };
      this.listener = this.listener.bind(this);
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
      this.subscription = ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener(this.listener);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      ScreenOrientation.removeOrientationChangeListener(this.subscription);
    }

    listener(changeEvent) {
      const { orientationInfo } = changeEvent;
      this.setState({
        orientation: orientationInfo.orientation.split('_')[0],
      });
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
      await this.detectOrientation();
    }

    async detectOrientation() {
      const { orientation } = await ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync();
      this.setState({
        orientation: orientation.split('_')[0],
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component
          {...this.props}
          {...this.state}
          onLayout={this.detectOrientation}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  return (props) => <DetectOrientation {...props} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a more performant integration, I used the following as a superclass for each of my react-navigation screens:

```
export default class BaseScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('screen')

    // use this to avoid setState errors on unmount
    this._isMounted = false

    this.state = {
      screen: {
        orientation: width < height,
        height: height,
        width: width
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => this.updateScreen())
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false
    Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', () => this.updateScreen())
  }

  updateScreen = () => {
    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('screen')

    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({
        screen: {
          orientation: width < height,
          width: width, height: height
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Set any root components to extend from this component, and then pass the screen state to your leaf/dumb components from the inheriting root components.

Additionally, to keep from adding to the performance overhead, change the style object instead of adding more components to the mix:

```
const TextObject = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={[styles.main, screen.orientation ? styles.column : styles.row]}>
    <Text style={[styles.text, screen.width > 600 ? {fontSize: 14} : null ]}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  column: {
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  main: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 10
  }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future, and you'll find it to be quite optimal in terms of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `styled-components`, and this is how I re-render the UI on orientation change.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import appTheme from 'constants/appTheme';

const App = () => {
  // Re-Layout on orientation change
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(appTheme.getTheme());
  const onLayout = () => {
    setTheme(appTheme.getTheme());
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <View onLayout={onLayout}/>
      {/* Components */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Even if you're not using `styled-components`, you can create a state and update it on `onLayout` to re-render the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Note for the case with a pure component. @mridul-tripathi answer works correctly, but if a pure component is used, then probably only parent/top-level component reacting to orientation change is not enough. You will also need to update a pure component separately  on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```js
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function useOrientation() {
  const window = useWindowDimensions();

  return window.height >= window.width ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `useWindowDimensions`
This hook re-render component when dimension change and apply styles but `Dimensions` object can't re-render component and change style, it just work in first render

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
```

then destructure it

```
const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
```

and final you can do like this

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const isPortrait = height > width;

  return (
    <View style={isPortrait ? styles.portrait : styles.landscape}>
      {/* something */}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  portrait: {},
  landscape: {},
});

export default App;
```

also you can use `scale` property

```
const { scale } = useWindowDimensions();
```

read this document
https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions

Comment: While `useWindowDimensions` has a convenient syntax it has currently a few bugs on ios, while rotating the screen: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35800 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29290

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this hook and works fine for me. The **useWindowDimensions** hook from react-native will automatically update your window **height** and **width** on orientation change so!.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native'
    
    type Orientation = 'PORTRAIT' | 'LANDSCAPE'
    
    
    const useOrientation = () => {
    
        const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions()
    
        const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState<Orientation>(height > width ? 'PORTRAIT' : 'LANDSCAPE')
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setOrientation(height > width ? 'PORTRAIT' : 'LANDSCAPE')
    
        }, [height, width])
    
    
        return { orientation, width, height }
    }
    export default useOrientation;
```

Comment: This answer seems to have already been proposed few times ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73370846/10952503), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062501/10952503)), and seems to have an [issue while rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683591/react-native-different-styles-applied-on-orientation-change/78039564#comment132579132_73370846).