# Change Style When Orientation in React Native?

Tags: react-native, screen-orientation, react-native-stylesheet

I am using Function class in react native, now I open my app in portrait my screen design changes if I open the app in landscape my design works fine how to render the stylesheet in function class every time I change the orientation of the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683591/react-native-different-styles-applied-on-orientation-change

Comment: @Abe I have a different problem if I open the app in landscape it works fine but if I open the app in portrait the style gets changed & the [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen] works for the class component but my screen design is in function component is there any solution for function class.